# Can I get an array as an option argument in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-scripting

I am writing a shell script and wants to pass multiple options in an argument. Is it possible to do that like using getopts?

Requirement example:

```
./shell.sh -d db1 db2
```

should pass the values `db1` and `db2` as the values of the `-d` option.

Answer (score 4):

You can use one option multiple times and collect results in the array:

```
./shell.sh -d db1 -d db2
```

Code:

```
while getopts "d:" opt
do
  case ${opt} in
    d) dbs+=("$OPTARG");;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

No. But you pass a single argument joined with, for example, a colon; or quoted

```
./shell.sh -d db1:db2 
./shell.sh -d "db1 db2"
```

In the first case:

```
while getopts d: opt; do
    case $opt in
        d) IFS=: read -a dbs <<< "$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done
```

In the 2nd case (quoted)

```
        d) set -f          # turn off filename expansion
           dbs=($OPTARG)   # variable is unquoted
           set +f;;        # turn it back on
```